# Find country from domain name and put result in text file

Tags: python, dns

I have this script below how check the countries of domaine names. and i want to put each country code in a specific file.

For example :

FR ==> FR.txt
US ==> US.TXT

The script output is like this :

### domain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]: US

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from geolite2 import geolite2

def origin(ip, domain_str, result):
    print("{0} [{1}]: {2}".format(domain_str.strip(), ip, result))

def getip(domain_str):
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain_str.strip())
    reader = geolite2.reader()      
    output = reader.get(ip)
    result = output['country']['iso_code']
    origin(ip, domain_str, result)

with open("hostnames.txt", "r") as ins:
    for domain_str in ins:
        try:
            getip(domain_str)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("{0} [could not resolve]".format(domain_str.strip())) 
            if len(domain_str) > 2:
                subdomain = domain_str.split('.', 1)[1]
                try:
                    getip(subdomain)
                except:
                    continue

geolite2.close()
```

I appreciate any help provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def origin(ip, domain_str, result):
    file_name = "{}.txt".format(result)
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write("{}".format(domain_str.strip()))
```

Comment: shahaf thank u the code is working but i don't want the ip to be printed in the text file just the domain:
EX:
domain1
domain2
domain3